# How to point domain to wordpress page

Tags: apache, virtual-hosts

I currently have a Wordpress "folder" at `/my-page/`. This is a htaccess rewritten url so obviously doesn't exist.

I need to point a domain to this folder so that for `www.my-page-domain.com` the Base url is actually `/my-page/`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add that folder path in the `.htaccess`, your `.htaccess` should be in the folder as well.

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /my-page/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /my-page/index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```